# strange setRedirect action on joomla

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, controller

I saw a strange behavior with the `setRedirect` function inside a `controller` on Joomla!
I have a method on admin that allows login as an user. The strange thing is that it works perfectly in some machines and in others the admin is redirected but without logged in.

I dicovery that the problem happened with Joomla's `setRedirect` because `header()` php funcion works perfectly. Somebody have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

```
public function loginFromAdmin()
{
    $userid = JRequest::getVar('id');
    $user = JUser::getInstance($userid);
    $session =& JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('user', $user);

    $this->setRedirect('https://abc.com/index.php/xyz');
}
```

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I'm using Joomla! 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect('https://abc.com/index.php/xyz');
```

Hope this helps.